# When Using Native Extensions (ANE) with Flashbuilder 4.5/6 can I 'export release build' or do I have to compile with command line?

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder4.5

Am I overlooking something or is it really true that to create the final .APK file for an android app I have built in fb 4.5 / 4.6 I have to really use the command line or will it work if I just do export release build as I normally do?

I've experimented with it trying to add vibration but the process seemed really overly complicated and frustrating and it never worked in the end.

Comment: You can export a release build normally.  Did you try it before posting?Is there a reason this didn't work for you?

Comment: ok, back to the drawing board then... i may have been using an old(er) tutorial or video walkthrough then.... I recall it speaking about  fb 4.6 like it was a future, pending release...   I'll go back to the drawing board and go step by step and see if I can get it to work right.  Thanks a lot for the feedback...  I thought it seemed weird that such a well rounded piece of software would make a user go through all those hoops.  Im really enjoying learning FB and appreciate all the help you've been providing along my journey.

Comment: I do not remember which version of the IDE ANE support was introduced.  It may be 4.6 and higher.  Lots of hoops to jump through before that.  But, pretty easy now once you have the ANE coded.

Comment: I finally got the vibration ANE to work with FB 4.6 - and can see how much easier it is than the earlier version(s)...  question:  I notice now, however, that when Im debugging on my macbook pro (using emulator, not usb connected device) I get nasty errors that seem to point to the fact that the mac os cant do vibration... is this normal or is there a way I can just have it behave like a non-vibration capable phone and just ignore the vibration commands.  I am checking for the capability in the code to properly handle non-capable devices, but hope I can still debug from my machine alone.

Comment: In my experience; debugging a mobile app on an emulator is a waste of time and energy.  The lack of touch input; or features such as the vibration you're experiencing, make the experience subpar.  Your code should somehow 'casually' handle the problem if no vibration exists; but if you didn't build your own native extension that may be easier said than done.

Comment: Makes sense I guess... mainly I am using emulation as a quick way to a) learn / familiarize myself with the basics but moreso, b) for layout testing...    I am basically just commenting out the vibration function and when done and ready to publish will uncomment those few lines.  -- building my own ANE - well I dont think Im quite there yet but would like to look into that later.  right now the iOS dev signup and ios publishing to-do list has me busy.  thanks again.